# Should we call CFRelease of addressBook after creating it

Tags: objective-c

After

```
ABAddressBookRef  adBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, NULL);
```

Should we latter call

```
CFRelease(adBook);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As usual, if you own the object, you have to release it. Since copy indicates that a copy of the object is transferred into your ownership, you should release it. This does account for all CF objects as well.